# I am getting error in test class because of saml is not enabled

Tags: apex, login, saml, mydomain

I am getting this error-

> System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 1757874930-20679
>   (1748552322) (1748552322)  System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce
>   System Error: 1757874930-20679 (1748552322) (1748552322)  Stack Trace:
>   Class.Auth.AuthConfiguration.getSamlSsoUrl: line 279, column 1
>   Class.MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler.getSsoRedirect: line 55, column
>   1 Class.MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler.login: line 24, column 1
>   Class.MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandlerTest.partnerUserValidation: line
>   126, column 1

**Test class**

```
        @isTest
    public class MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandlerTest {
        @testSetup 
        public static void setup() { 
            try {
                User sysAdminUser = new User(
                    ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'].Id,
                    LastName = 'last',
                    Email = 'testUser2FA@test.com',
                    Username = 'testUser2FA@test.com',
                    CompanyName = 'TEST',
                    Title = 'title',
                    Alias = 'tuser',
                    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US'
                );
                insert sysAdminUser;

                User restrictedUser = new User(
                    ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Restricted'].Id,
                    LastName = 'last',
                    Email = 'testUser2FA@test.com',
                    Username = 'TelstraCustomPerm@test.com',
                    CompanyName = 'TEST',
                    Title = 'title',
                    Alias = 'Permtest',
                    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                    FederationIdentifier='R00100' 
                );
                insert restrictedUser;   

                // Create PermissionSet with Custom Permission and assign to test user
                PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet();
                ps.Name = 'Test';
                ps.Label = 'Test';
                insert ps;

                SetupEntityAccess sea = new SetupEntityAccess();
                sea.ParentId = ps.Id;
                sea.SetupEntityId = [select Id from CustomPermission where DeveloperName = 'Telstra_Administrator'][0].Id;
                insert sea;

                System.debug('sea>>>>'+sea);
                PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment();
                psa.AssigneeId = restrictedUser.id;
                psa.PermissionSetId = ps.Id;
                insert psa;

                User usr = new User(
                    ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'CDM Admin'].Id,
                    LastName = 'last',
                    Email = 'testUser2FA@test.com',
                    Username = 'nocustompermission@test.com',
                    CompanyName = 'TEST',
                    Title = 'title',
                    Alias = 'alias',
                    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                    FederationIdentifier='C00100' 
                );
                insert usr; 

                User partnerUser = new User(
                    ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Partner Stores'].Id,
                    LastName = 'last',
                    Email = 'testUser2FA@test.com',
                    Username = 'partnerProfile@test.com',
                    CompanyName = 'TEST',
                    Title = 'title',
                    Alias = 'alias',
                    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                    FederationIdentifier='P00100' 
                );
                insert partnerUser; 
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }      
        }

        public static testmethod void CustomPermValidation(){

            try {  
                user u=[select id,FederationIdentifier,Username from user where username='TelstraCustomPerm@test.com'];
                Map<String, String> requestAttributes = new Map<String, String>();
                String startUrl = '';
                MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler sa=new MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler();
                PageReference  pageReference =  sa.login(u.FederationIdentifier,startUrl,requestAttributes);
                System.assertNotEquals(null, pageReference, 'Page reference was not returned');
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }   

        public static testmethod void noCustomPermValidation(){

            try {
                user u=[select id,FederationIdentifier from user where username='nocustompermission@test.com' limit 1];
                Map<String, String> requestAttributes = new Map<String, String>();
                String startUrl = '';
                MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler sa=new MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler();
                PageReference  pageReference =  sa.login(u.FederationIdentifier,startUrl,requestAttributes);
                System.assertNotEquals(null, pageReference, 'Page reference was not returned');
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }

        public static testmethod void partnerUserValidation(){

            try {
                user u=[select id,profile.name,FederationIdentifier from user where username='partnerProfile@test.com' limit 1];
                Map<String, String> requestAttributes = new Map<String, String>();
                system.debug('upro---->'+u.profile.name);
                String startUrl = '';
                MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler sa=new MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler();
                PageReference  pageReference =  sa.login(u.FederationIdentifier,startUrl,requestAttributes);
                System.assertNotEquals(null, pageReference, 'Page reference was not returned');
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
        /*public static testmethod void testcaal(){
    user u=[select id,FederationIdentifier,Username from user where username='testUser2FA@test.com'];
    test.startTest();
    Map<String, String> requestAttributes = new Map<String, String>();
    String startUrl = '';
    MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler sa=new MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler();
    PageReference  pageReference = sa.login(u.username,startUrl,requestAttributes);

    }*/
        @isTest static void testLoginWithInvalidUser() {
            try {
                Map<String, String> requestAttributes = new Map<String, String>();
                String startUrl = '';
                String fedId = 'AETERYD';
                MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler myDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler = new MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler();
                // Invoke login method from handler with non-existing user
                myDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler.login(fedId, startUrl, requestAttributes);
            }catch (Auth.LoginDiscoveryException loginDiscoveryException) {
                // Assert exception message
                System.assert(loginDiscoveryException.getMessage().contains('No unique user found'), 'message=' + loginDiscoveryException.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Apex class--

```
            /*******************************************************
        @name: MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler
        @CreateDate: 21/05/2019
        @Description: This class is used to redirect login flow based on permissions
        @Version: 1.0
        @reference: 
        *******************************************************/
        public with sharing class MyDomainDiscLoginDefaultHandler implements Auth.MyDomainLoginDiscoveryHandler {
            public PageReference login(String identifier, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
                if (identifier != null) {
                    //Query user by Fedaration ID  
                    List<User> users = new list<user>([SELECT Id,profile.name,username,FederationIdentifier FROM User WHERE FederationIdentifier = :identifier  AND IsActive = TRUE]);

                    //Query user by Username and filter with System administrator.
                    List<User> SysAdminUsers = new list<user>([SELECT Id,profile.name,Username,FederationIdentifier FROM User WHERE Username = :identifier AND IsActive = TRUE and Profile.Name='System Administrator']);

                    //If multiple records found with same identifier
                    if(users.size()>1 || SysAdminUsers.size()>1) {
                        throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('Multiple Users found with Same UserName/FederationIdentifier');
                    }
                    if(users.size() == 1) {
                        if(users[0].profile.name.equals(Label.PIMS_Partner_Profile)) {
                            System.debug('Inside telstra Retail partner permission>>>>>');
                            return getSsoRedirect(Label.PIMS_Partner_Login,users[0], startUrl, requestAttributes); //call sso flow 
                        }
                        else if(doesRunningUserHavePermission(Label.Telstra_Administrator,users)){
                            System.debug('Inside telstra administrtaor permission>>>>>');
                            return getSsoRedirect(Label.Telstra_RSA_Account_01,users[0], startUrl, requestAttributes); //call sso flow 
                        }
                        else {
                        System.debug('inside else>>>>>>');
                            return getSsoRedirect(Label.Telstra_Account_01,users[0], startUrl, requestAttributes); //call sso flow 
                        }
                    }
                    else if(SysAdminUsers.size()==1) {

                            return normalLogin(SysAdminUsers[0],startUrl, requestAttributes);

                    }
                    else {
                            throw new Auth.LoginDiscoveryException('No unique user found.'); 
                    }  
                }
                throw new Auth.DiscoveryCustomErrorException('Invalid Identifier');
            }

           /*******************************************************
            @MethodName: getSsoRedirect
            @Arguments: list,String,map
            @Description: This method is used redirecting specific SSO
            *******************************************************/
            private PageReference getSsoRedirect(String DeveloperName,User user, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
                // You can look up if the user should log in with SAML or an Auth Provider and return the URL to initialize SSO. For example:
                SamlSsoConfig SSO = [select Id from SamlSsoConfig where developerName=:developerName limit 1];
                String ssoUrl = Auth.AuthConfiguration.getSamlSsoUrl(requestAttributes.get('MyDomainURL'), startUrl, SSO.Id);
                System.debug('requestAttributes>>>>>'+requestAttributes);
                System.debug('SSO>>>>>'+SSO);
                System.debug('ssoUrl >>>>>'+ssoUrl );
                if(ssoUrl!=null || ssoUrl!='') {
                    return new PageReference(ssoUrl);
                }
                return null;
            }

            /*******************************************************
            @MethodName: normalLogin
            @Arguments: list,String,map
            @Description: This method is used redirecting to Normal login Flow
            *******************************************************/
            private PageReference normalLogin(User user, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
                return Auth.SessionManagement.finishLoginDiscovery(Auth.LoginDiscoveryMethod.password, user.Id);    
            }

            /*******************************************************
            @MethodName: doesRunningUserHavePermission
            @Arguments: CustomPermission name and User List
            @Description: This method is used for checking user is having custom permission assigned
            *******************************************************/
            public static Boolean doesRunningUserHavePermission(String CustomPermissionName,list <user>users) {
                Set<Id> accessiblePermissionIds = new Set<Id>();
                for (SetupEntityAccess access : [SELECT SetupEntityId FROM SetupEntityAccess
                                   WHERE SetupEntityType = 'CustomPermission' AND ParentId IN (
                                     SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment
                                     WHERE Assignee.FederationIdentifier =:users[0].FederationIdentifier)])

                accessiblePermissionIds.add(access.SetupEntityId);
                return 0 < [SELECT count() FROM CustomPermission WHERE Id IN :accessiblePermissionIds AND DeveloperName =: CustomPermissionName];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [AuthConfiguration.getSamlSsoUrl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthConfiguration.htm#apex_Auth_AuthConfiguration_methods) doc:

> Parameters
>
> *communityUrl*
>
> Type: `String`
>
> The URL for the community or My
>   Domain subdomain. If not null and not specified as an empty string,
>   you get the URL for a community. If null or specified as an empty
>   string, you get the URL for a My Domain subdomain.

You should be passing `null` instead of `requestAttributes.get('MyDomainURL')` as the first argument when you call `getSamlSsoUrl(...)` for the baseline MyDomain-ed org.